# How to return the second to last character in a string using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I am trying to only return the second to last character from a string using MS SQL.

I've tried using MID and Substring but the length of the string isn't always the same for the column I am trying to return, So I can't do it that way.

So say I am returning the codes of something:

```
Code
'1234'
```

I want to just return '3' from that code.

How can I do this?
Cheers in advance :)

Comment: For sure you can use substring on variable column lengths

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`SUBSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187748.aspx) and [`LEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190329.aspx). LEN gives you the length of the string, then subtract 1 to get the previous char:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Code, LEN(Code)-1,1)
```

Comment: Thanks so much new to this and this problem has been bugging me for hours!!

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
select left(right(code, 2), 1) from MyTable;
```

You might need to validate that the string actually has at least 2 chars, however.

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/39eb9/1)